# how do I export namespace'd TypeScript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some TS code that was generated by a 3rd party lib that looks like this:

```js
export namespace com {

    namespace rynop {

        namespace alaynapage {

            interface IPage {
                id?: (string|null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to re-export the `IPage` interface from a new file (lets call it `page.model.ts`) so that I don't have to do the following every time I want to use this interface:

```js
import { com } from '../../shared/apiclient';

export class Page implements com.rynop.alaynapage.IPage {

   // Or use it as a param type...
   factory(data: com.rynop.alaynapage.IPage) {
   }
}
```

I've tried:

```js
export { com.rynop.alaynapage.IPage as IPage } from '../../shared/apiclient';
// Error: has no exported member alaynapage
```

```js
import { com } from '../../shared/apiclient';

export const IPage = com.rynop.alaynapage.IPage;
// Error: IPage' does not exist on type 'typeof alaynapage'. Did you mean 'Page`?
// Makes sense cuz interface can't be const
```

How do I do this?  I potentially have the option to change the generated code, but would prefer not to.

Comment: Have you tried `export type IPage = com.rynop.alaynapage.IPage;`

Comment: Have you tried to extend it, export interface IPage extends com.rynop.....IPage { }

Comment: Yup, gives "An interface declaring no members is equivalent to its supertype. [no-empty-interface]"